# why I can not use bsm message in TraCIDemo?

Tags: veins

I am using omnetpp 5.4.1, veins 4.7.1 and sumo-0.30.0.
I am writing my own code in TraCIDemo11p and I really need to use bsm message. but TraCIDemo11p does not let me to use it.
For instance I created an array into handlepositionupdate method of TraCIDemo11p class because I wanted to add bsm at it. but I encountered with runtime error whereas when I add wsa and wsm no error is occurred.
what is my problem. 
I really need help and I appreciate any guidance.
my code is :
    void TraCIDemo11p::handlePositionUpdate(cObject* obj) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::handlePositionUpdate(obj);

```
// stopped for for at least 10s?
if (mobility->getSpeed() < 1) {
    if (simTime() - lastDroveAt >= 10 && sentMessage == false) {
        findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,red");
        sentMessage = true;

        WaveShortMessage* wsm = new WaveShortMessage();
        populateWSM(wsm);
        wsm->setWsmData(mobility->getRoadId().c_str());


        //host is standing still due to crash
        if (dataOnSch) {
            startService(Channels::SCH2, 42, "Traffic Information Service");
            //started service and server advertising, schedule message to self to send later
            scheduleAt(computeAsynchronousSendingTime(1,type_SCH),wsm);
        }
        else {
            //send right away on CCH, because channel switching is disabled
            sendDown(wsm);
        }
    }
}
else {
    lastDroveAt = simTime();
}
```

Coord senderPosition = mobility->getCurrentPosition();

```
//Get all available nodes in simulation
std::map<std::string, cModule*> availableCars = mobility->getManager()-
```

> getManagedHosts();

```
//Iterate through collection and find distance,
std::map<std::string, cModule*>::iterator it;

for(it = availableCars.begin(); it != availableCars.end(); it++)
{

    TraCIMobility* mobility1 = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(it->second);
    Coord receiverPosition = mobility1->getCurrentPosition(); 

   double distance=senderPosition.distance(receiverPosition);

    std::cout<<"we defined distance"<<endl;
    WaveShortMessage* wsm = new WaveShortMessage();
    BasicSafetyMessage* bsm = new BasicSafetyMessage();

    wsm->setDistance(distance);

   cArray array("array1");
   array.add(wsm);

    double dist[400];
    double TheMax=dist[0];

  for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
   std::cout<< wsm->getDistance() << endl;
   dist[i]=wsm->getDistance();
   if(dist[i]>TheMax){
   TheMax=dist[i];
    int index=i;
    std::cout<<"the max distance is "<<TheMax<<endl;
   }}

  simtime_t T=simTime()+60;
      Coord senderPosition1=mobility->getPositionAt(T);

       double direction1=mobility->getAngleRad();
  std::map<std::string, cModule*> availableCars = mobility->getManager()- 
  >getManagedHosts();

      std::map<std::string, cModule*>::iterator it;

 for(it = availableCars.begin(); it != availableCars.end(); it++)
   {



       TraCIMobility* mobility2 = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(it->second);

       double direction2=mobility2->getAngleRad();

       Coord receiverPosition1=mobility2->getPositionAt(T);

         if(direction2!=direction1){

          std::cout<<"they move in opposite direction"<<endl;
         }
          double distance1=senderPosition.distance(receiverPosition);
          std::cout<<"the first distance is "<<distance1 <<endl;

          WaveShortMessage* wsm = new WaveShortMessage();
          BasicSafetyMessage* bsm = new BasicSafetyMessage();
          cArray array("array1");
          int index = array.add(wsm);
         double distance2=senderPosition1.distance(receiverPosition1);

          std::cout<<"the second distance is:"<<distance2<<endl;
          if(distance2>distance1){
            std::cout<<"they are getting far away"<<endl;
            array.remove(wsm);
         }  } }}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show your code and the error as well?

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply I inserted my code in my question

Comment: Thanks, now, hopefully people are able to answer your question. I am not a veins expert so I wouldn't know ;-)

Comment: The Veins FAQ at <http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/> has an entry on "what happened? My simulation crashed!". Maybe this can serve as a starting point for finding your error.